# SPRING XD- Duplicate Entries in HDFS SINK

Tags: hadoop, spring-xd

I am using spring xd singlenode for streaming data from an jdbc source (sql database) into HDFS. I am getting the data into hdfs but it is repeating the query many times and I am getting duplicate data. I have tried many options but it is not working. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the jdbchdfs job instead?

Comment: Thanks for the reply now I am using JDBCHDFS job for data streaming. but now it is not taking the increamental data load. Everytime when I insert a new row to table I have to undeploy, deploy and then launch a job which creates a new file with whole table data into it with along with newly inserted row. I have tried using different queries and options but not getting to any point. I want to write the newly inserted data into the same file until it will be rolled over. It will also help in accessing live data.

Comment: Ah.  Unfortunately the jdbchdfs job does not currently support incremental loads.  It's on our road map and will probably be in the next release.  Unfortunately for that functionality, I'd just copy the current jdbchdfs job and add the incremental functionality so that when the next revision is made available, you can just swap them out.

Comment: Thanks Michael for replying. Till then we will explore some other option  to get desired output.

Comment: when is next  release scheduled ?

Answer (score 0):

u maybe ignore the udpate sql to avoide same data like these:
`<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter query="select * from item where status=2"
 channel="target" data-source="dataSource"
 update="update item set status=10 where id in (:id)" />`